# What are my production/storage bonuses?

Tags: kittens-game

[When do I get those really expensive metaphysics upgrades with the weird names?](https://wiki.kittensgame.com/en/guides-and-advice-and-stuff/monstrous-advice#when-do-i-get-those-really-expensive-metaphysics-upgrades-with-the-weird-names) mentions production and storage bonuses. Where do I find those? The closest I've found is the "Craft effectiveness: +N%" in the Workshop tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretaion of the page is that the table does not list bonuses. It lists how much paragon you want to have before buying the upgrade to not lose out on the bonuses paragon gives you.

If instead you are asking more simply "what is the bonus that paragon gives me?", this can be found on the Paragon page:
https://wiki.kittensgame.com/en/general-information/resources/paragon

You get 1% more production to everything, up to a cap, per paragon you have. You gain 0.1% more storage to everything, with no cap, per paragon you have. There are further caveats, but that is the basics of it.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, I need 10.5k paragon to break even on the storage bonus when buying Malkuth?

Comment: @l0b0 That is how I understand it, yes.